# Ignore Debugger Attributes When Debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm finding myself having to debug externally provided libraries that I can't modify (or have the source code for). This code unfortunately has debugging attributes sprinkled everywhere, causing my debugging journey to be just a little painful.

Is there a way to have Visual Studio's debugger ignore the `DebuggerStepperBoundaryAttribute`/`DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute` when debugging non-user code?

Comment: [There](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/using-the-debuggernonusercode-attribute-in-visual-studio-2015/) is an article about some registry tricks for exception handling for VS2015. Have a look, maybe it'll be helpful for you